# rails 3 and PDFkit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit).

When I'm adding `.pdf` to my url it does nothing. My controller has:

```
respond_to :html, :pdf.
```

My mime type has been declared.

I tried this too:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf {
    html = render_to_string(:layout => false , :action => "www.google.fr")
    kit = PDFKit.new(html)
    send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => "candidats.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf')
    return # to avoid double render call
  }
end
```

but it does not work and I don't get errors. My browser keep waiting for localhost, but nothing happens.

So how should I try to use pdfkit ?

edit 2 :

According to my rails' logs, rails render successfully the HTML. I saw this in the .log, rails doesn't send it to webrick nor to my browser. And my browser keeps waiting, and waiting and nothing happen. I only have little pictures here.

edit 3 : My webrick server seem unable to respond to other request, once he starts getting a `.pdf` version of my url, any ideas ?

edit 4 :

I am using rails 3.1, wkhtmltopdf 0.9.5 (windows installer) and pdfkit 0.5.2

Comment: sorry, can't help you with your problem, but thanks for introducing pdfkit to me! always thought prawn was as 'good' as it gets.

Comment: There's a rather huge mismatch between the code you posted and the one that's shown on the tutorial you linked to. Are you sure you're following the tutorial?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a better way to access my .pdf urls even in developpement mode.

```
# Enable threaded mode
config.threadsafe!

# Code is not reloaded between requests
#config.cache_classes = true
```

Config.cache_classes is a comment, cause i had some problems when it wasn't. This way pdfkit works wonder even with rails 3.1. But, you don't reload code between requests.

That's not really a problem, cause you first work on your html, and you switch configuration, in order to check the pdf result. This way you don't have to bother about your production database.

Comment: Putting this setting in development mode does the job,  but how do you get it to work in Production (do you use heroku?).  If I set the `config.threadsafe!` flag in production my job times out.

Comment: I'm not using heroku. It works perfectly for me in production. (But i'm in local still).  This might help you : http://jguimont.com/post/2627758108/pdfkit-and-its-middleware-on-heroku . i havn't tryied.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to another stack overflow answer I got part of solution.

This works:

```
html = '<html><body>Toto de combats</body></html>'
@pdf = PDFKit.new(html)

send_data @pdf.to_pdf, :filename => "whatever.pdf",
                  :type => "application/pdf",
                  :disposition  => "attachement"
```

You can replace `attachement` by `inline,` so the pdf is displayed in your browser.

In the stack overflow answer I spoke about (I don't remember the link), the `.to_pdf` was missing, but is mandatory. Otherwise PDF reader doesn't recognize it.

I'm trying to get this work with a .pdf url.

Edit 3:

My problem with .pdf urls is solved. known issue with rails 3.1, but google was unable to find them.

explanation : [explanation](https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit/issues/110)

Workaround (hadn't tryied yet). [workaround](http://jguimont.com/post/2627758108/pdfkit-and-its-middleware-on-heroku)