# How to install PDFKit? (Rails 3.2.1 and PDFKit 0.5.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, installation, pdfkit

I'm trying to use PDFKit.

It looks fairly straightforward so I'm trying to follow [Ryan's Rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit?autoplay=true).

So I added the gem to my GemFile and updated my `application.rb` with:

```
config.middleware.use "PDFKit::Middleware"
```

After that I installed wkhtmltopdf on linux with:

```
apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

And I make sure it works:

```
[nicolas@Minto]%wkhtmltopdf www.google.com gogole.pdf
Loading page (1/2)
Printing pages (2/2)                                               
Done
```

Everything looks good until I try to add the .pdf on one of my pages...

The website stays in a loading state forever. When I stop the server with a `Ctrl - C` in the console, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError (command failed: "/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf" "--page-size" "Letter" "--margin-top" "0.75in" "--margin-right" "0.75in" "--margin-bottom" "0.75in" "--margin-left" "0.75in" "--encoding" "UTF-8" "--print-media-type" "--quiet" "-" "-"):
  pdfkit (0.5.2) lib/pdfkit/pdfkit.rb:71:in `to_pdf'
  pdfkit (0.5.2) lib/pdfkit/middleware.rb:21:in `call'
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: I think you are using `Webrick` as HTTP web server. Can you try to use `Thin`?

Comment: @nash: Thank you for showing me Thin (I usually use mongrel but I was indeed using Webrick, shame on me :p). Anyway it's doing the same thing with Thin :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so,

Took a few hours of googling but I finally found the solution in an other stackoverflow question:
[pdfkit not rendering correctly in rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017042/pdfkit-not-rendering-correctly-in-rails-3-1)

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I recently played with PDFKit and got it to work in my rails application and faced a similar problem.
The three steps you need are :

1. You will need to put **gem "pdfkit"** in your GemFile.
2. Put **config.middleware.use PDFKit::Middleware** in **application.rb** file which you already have.
3. Try putting the following code in **pdfkit.rb** file under **'config/initializers'** folder.

   PDFKit.configure do |config|

   config.wkhtmltopdf = 'C:\software\utilities\wkhtmltopdf\wkhtmltopdf.exe' #Path to your wkhtmltppdf installation directory

   config.root_url = "http://localhost" # Use only if your external hostname is unavailable on the server.

   end

Comment: Thank you, I tried your solution but my path was already correct!

Answer (score 0):

I also followed [Ryan's Rails cast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit).

PDFkit is dependent on wkhtmltopdf.rb. Any version > 0.9.9 has been causing the PDF creation process to hang just prior to completion, requiring a Ctrl - C. I use OS X 10.6.8, not Linux. However try:

```
wkhtmltopdf --version
```

If it is > 0.9.9, then rollback to 0.9.9. Solved my problem. Took me hours to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

We have a related problem here: [PDF Generation hangs using PDFKit and wkhtmotopdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045327/pdf-generation-hangs-using-pdfkit-and-wkhtmotopdf)

Quoting the solution from [Beerlington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/167614/beerlington):

> Try removing any javascript include tags from your HTML and see if that at least lets the PDF render. If that works, then you at least have a starting point.

I tried that and that worked for me.

I think it has to do with assets like javascript and stylesheets with relative path.