# Having trouble using pdfkit in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdfkit

I need to use pdfkit gem. I have installed gem, and wkhtmltopdftool as written in gem githubpage.(I installed wkhtmltopdf using homebrew). Now, I was doing anything as said in railscast about pdf kit. But when I add extension

> .pdf

to my url. It start loading, and nothing happens. Loading is never finished, except I close rails server. 
Also when I start loading .pdf url. I have wkhmtltopdf process started.(also icon of wkhtmltopdf appeared in panel)
What i am doing wrong? I am using rails 3.1.2 and ruby 1.9.2.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be similar to an [issue I ran into](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10045327/pdf-generation-hangs-using-pdfkit-and-wkhtmotopdf) recently where it was hanging on the javascript processing. Try removing any javascript include tags from your HTML and see if that at least lets the PDF render. If that works, then you at least have a starting point.