# Why does PDFKit/wkhtmltopdf hang but renders PDF as expected when Rails app is killed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, pdf, osx-mountain-lion, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

### Background

After reading around it seemed to me that [Prawn](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn) is out and [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) is in. It also seems like the [PDFKit](https://github.com/pdfkit/PDFKit) and [wicked_pdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) gems for Rails are the new cool. So I found a screencast by [Ryan](http://railscasts.com/) on [how to use PDFKit](http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit). I installed everything, tested wkhtmltopdf on the CLI with no problems, fiddled around with Rails settingsto run multiple processes so the asset pipeline works, and all seemed good, except I'm still stuck at the very end of the process (actually getting the PDF response from the server).

### Question

*When I request a `.pdf` version of my view (I'm using the PDFKit Middleware option) my browser just sits there waiting for a response, but as soon as I kill the Rails process the PDF I expected to get only then pops up in my browser window. What gives?*

### What I'm Using

- OS: OSX 10.8.1
- Rails: 3.2.8
- Ruby: 1.9.3
- wkhtmltopdf: 0.11.0_rc1 (although when I run `wkhtmltopdf -V` it says 0.10.0_rc2)
- qt: 4.8.2

### What I've Done

- used the PDFKit middleware by loading `config.middleware.use "PDFKit::Middleware"` in my `application.rb` file.
- included `gem 'pdfkit'` in my Gemfile and installed it with Bundler
- set the `.pdf` mime-type in my `mime_types.rb` initializer with `Mime::Type.register_alias "application/pdf", :pdf`
- added `config.threadsafe!` to `config/environments/development.rb` for multiple threads so asset pipeline doesn't conflict with PDF engine
- tested `wkhtmltopdf http://www.google.com google.pdf` and it generated a PDF of the Google homepage as expected
- tried swapping PDFKit for wicked_pdf and encountered the same problem (hanging, but when Rails process is killed the PDF renders as expected)

### What it Looks Like

This is the regular html page rendered by Rails (I've blurred the client details):
[image]

This is the CLI output by Rails when I try to navigate to `localhost:3000/some/path.pdf`. (the app hangs while waiting for a response):
[image]

When I finally kill the Rails process with `ctrl-c` the PDF finally shows up in the browser as I expected to see it (CSS and HTML rendered properly, so assets seem to load fine):
[image]

### Conclusions So Far

Swapping PDFKit for wicked_pdf and getting the same results seems to make me think the problem isn't with those libraries, but something to do with my development environment. But wkhtmltopdf runs fine off the command line, so that makes me think that it and QT are doing their job. The problem must be in Rails. Maybe I'm not configuring something properly?

### Plea for Help

How do I determine *what* exactly the problem is and how do I fix it?

I'll love you if you can help me <3

### Update

I've also tried using an alternative method of rendering the PDF (with `.to_pdf`) without the middleware option as follows (doing this I commented out `config.middleware.use "PDFKit::Middleware"` from my `application.rb` file):

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
        html = '<html><body>This is a test.</body></html>'
        @pdf = PDFKit.new(html)

        send_data @pdf.to_pdf, 
            :filename => 'whatever.pdf', 
            :type => 'application/pdf', 
            :disposition => 'attachment'
    end
end
```

Comment: I wonder if this might have something to do with OSX 10.8? I'm waiting on my client to setup a production server on which I'll test things out again. Maybe a combination of using a multi-threaded server + a different *nix environment will help. Regardless this won't help me in development.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

The problem is with wkhtmltopdf itself, specifically, any version after 0.9.9. wkhtmltopdf hangs when run directly from the command-line.

Steps to correct:

```
brew uninstall wkhtmltopdf
cd /usr/local/Library/Formula/
git checkout 6e2d550 /usr/local/Library/Formula/wkhtmltopdf.rb
brew install wkhtmltopdf
```

Then verify the correct version is installed `wkhtmltopdf --version` which should yield `wkhtmltopdf 0.9.9`

Citations:

1. https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/110
2. http://wearepandr.com/blog/article/homebrew-and-installing-old-package-versions#blog_nav

Comment: Steps 2-4 in a single command: `brew install https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/6e2d550cf4961129a790bfb0973f8e88704f439d/Library/Formula/wkhtmltopdf.rb`

Comment: If you have Ruby installed, you can bypass all of this Homebrew manipulation and just `gem install wkhtmltopdf`.

Delete the existing Homebrew symlink: `rm /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`.

Then link to the gem's binary e.g. `ln -s ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`. Use `which wkhtmltopdf` command to find the binary.

Add `gem 'wkhtmltopdf'` to the GemFile.

If using the `wicked_pdf` gem, set its configuration to `WickedPdf.config={exe_path: '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'}`.

References:
wkhtmltopdf gem (0.1.2) installs wkhtmltopdf binary version 0.8.3 patched qt.

Comment: The gemfile ```gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'``` currently installs 0.9.9 for those interested in using a gem instead of brew

Comment: I was attempting to use 0.11.x and after pulling all my hair out (including chest hair) I found this answer and wept like a child. You, my friend, have saved me.

Comment: Even 0.9.9.3 is bad? I have these issues just after upgrading an app from Rails 3 to Rails 4 and Ruby from 1.9.3 to 2.2.1. I tried several versions of wkhtmltopdf ranging from 0.9.9 to 0.12.2.1 and generating PDF hangs for every version. I think that this must be related to Ruby version or PDFkit gem itself.

Comment: @januszm Many people are reporting success with the `wkhtmltopdf-binary` gem. If you need to run the latest version of wkhtmltopdf, try this fork of the gem https://github.com/dmitryrck/wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem

Comment: In my case it fails on images on Rails 4. After I removed all image tags from the html template (converted to pdf) it works (but no images). It worked well on Rails 3.2 so this is clearly related to the Rails upgrade. It's explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377401/pdfkit-hangs-when-generating-a-pdf-with-an-image

Comment: @scarver2 referring to your comment on Sep 26, 2015, does that mean the latest version of wkhtmltopdf no longer has the problem? Would we need to use the fork of the gem you recommended or could we just install the latest version with brew?

Comment: @Marklar The `wkhtmltopdf_binary` gem actually bypasses any Homebrew installation and uses the version found within gem's bin folder. The author, Dmitry Rocha, has been keeping the binaries current.

Comment: @scarver2 thanks for taking the time to answer. Are you sure the binaries are current in the gem even though the gem hasn't been updated in 4 years?

Comment: @Marklar Use this branch https://github.com/dmitryrck/wkhtmltopdf_binary_gem It was updated last month.

Comment: if you are getting `Please switch this formula to SHA256.` when installing the old version try `brew install https://gist.githubusercontent.com/semanticart/389944e2bcdba5424e01/raw/9ed120477b57daf10d7de6d585d49b2017cd6955/wkhtmltopdf.rb`. See: https://gist.github.com/semanticart/389944e2bcdba5424e01

Comment: Note that this now needs to be `brew cask uninstall wkhtmltopdf` and `brew cask install wkhtmltopdf`.

Answer (score 9):

Try the last version. The easy way install on MacOS:

```
brew install Caskroom/cask/wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: Wena abel, gracias! xD!

Answer (score 2):

The fix by [scarver2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14043085/778174) worked for me as advertised. But I needed a more recent version of `wkhtmltopdf`. Since the homebrew version still seems outdated (it still hangs on the command line), and since there isn't a recent precompiled binary available, I used the os x build script to compile one myself:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf.git
$ cd wkhtmltopdf
$ ./build_osx.sh     # i'm running 10.9.2
$ bin/wkhtmltopdf --version                                                                                  
Name:
  wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1-72a9f2066fe9ffd162dec007a4d9b6a5cd63b670
$ curl www.example.com | bin/wkhtmltopdf - test.pdf  # render pdf of example.com
$ open test.pdf   # to confirm pdf
```

I'm using `pdfkit 0.6.2` with `Rails 3.2.17`. I put the binary in `/vendor` and, in a `pdfkit` initializer, pointed to it with `config.wkhtmltopdf`. So far, so good.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue. It works when I added: 'config.threadsafe!' in application.rb as the answer in [the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531005/rails-3-and-pdfkit). Hope this help.

Comment: Yes, I've implemented `config.threadsafe!` in my development.rb file. I understand there can be a deadlock between wkhtmltopdf and the asset pipeline when using default webrick because it uses only one thread. My app was previously doing nothing before I did this, so this did indeed help get things a step further. However, it's still hanging while waiting for the PDF file (i guess the browser isn't receiving it from the server?)

Comment: It didn't work for me either until I switched from `thin` back to `webrick`.

Answer (score 0):

Exact same symptoms but using `WickedPdf` currently. At this point, I believe the issue lies with `wkhtmltopdf` as well.

Unfortunately, neither of the recommendations I've been able to find in Stack/Google worked for me. Instead, I needed to combine several suggestions, including some found in this post.

Solution was:

1. `brew uninstall wkhtmltopdf`
2. find and delete any copies of `wkhtmltopdf` in `/usr/bin`
3. comment `WickedPdf.config` line in `config/initializers`
4. add `config.threadsafe!` to `development.rb`
5. remove middleware and allow 'show' action of main controller to handle pdf requests (may not be necessary)
6. add `wkhtmltopdf-binary` to gemfile
7. bundle
8. restart server
9. You may also need to add `Mime::Type.register_alias "application/pdf", :pdf` to `config/initializers/mime_types.rb` (for me, this causes '*warning: already initialized constant PDF*')

My set-up was: Mac OSX Mountain Lion with Rails 3.2.1, Webrick, Postgres and wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.9.9.1).

Answer (score 0):

Mine was also hanging and opening the wkhtmltopdf icon in the dock.

I actually found the problem for me was I only had 1 unicorn worker process running. Once I added more than 1 it worked fine.

I'm running wkhtmltopdf 0.9.9 on OS X with pdfkit 0.6.2

Answer (score -2):

Try editing `config/initializer/pdfkit.rb` in the following way:

```
PDFKit.configure do |config|

config.wkhtmltopdf = Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf-i386').to_s

config.default_options = {

  :encoding=>"UTF-8",
  :page_size=>"A4",
  :margin_top=>"0.25in",
  :margin_right=>"0.1in",
  :margin_bottom=>"0.25in",
  :margin_left=>"0.1in",
  :disable_smart_shrinking=> false
}
end
```