# wicked_pdf timeout on unicorn when making a pdf

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, pdf, wicked-pdf

I am introducing `wicked_pdf` in my app and the generation of the pdf results very very slow.

When using thin I manage to obtain in many many minutes (more than 10) a pdf with the correct contents, but missing the css and the images.

I now switched to using unicorn with 3 workers, and the request fails after 60 seconds. So the pdf generation doesn't work at all.

here's the output from unicorn:

```
"***************\"/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf\" -q        \"file:////var/folders/hc/yp8ps4x54rg7clpzf7g6plwm0000gq/T/wicked_pdf20140123-25990-100u2wv.html\" \"/var/folders/hc/yp8ps4x54rg7clpzf7g6plwm0000gq/T/wicked_pdf_generated_file20140123-25990-1hakql5.pdf\" ***************"
E, [2014-01-23T15:45:03.391769 #25693] ERROR -- : worker=0 PID:25990 timeout (61s > 60s), killing
E, [2014-01-23T15:45:03.399291 #25693] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 25990 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=0
I, [2014-01-23T15:45:03.399536 #25693]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2014-01-23T15:45:03.401747 #26013]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=26013
I, [2014-01-23T15:45:03.402179 #26013]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
I, [2014-01-23T15:45:06.113099 #26013]  INFO -- : worker=0 ready
```

my show controller looks like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @item }
  format.pdf do
    render pdf: "#{current_user.username.dehumanize}_item_#{@item.id}"
  end
end
```

and I have reduced my `show.pdf.haml` to:

```
%html
  %head
  %body
    #wrapper
      .top_wrapper
        %header.top-header.border
          .container
            .row-fluid.header
              logo
              .span2
                logo2
        .container
          .row-fluid
      .body-wrapper
        .container
          .row
            .span4
              %h4 Comments
          .row
            .span9
      %footer
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured that the problem was `wkhtmltopdf` hanging after creating the pdf as a temp file.

I checked then in among the issues of `wkhtmltopdf` and found that this is an old known issue, which has still not been resolved.

The last working version that didn't have this problem was `0.9.9`.

Here the instructions to install it via brew:

[Why does PDFKit/wkhtmltopdf hang but renders PDF as expected when Rails app is killed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517640/why-does-pdfkit-wkhtmltopdf-hang-but-renders-pdf-as-expected-when-rails-app-is-k/14043085#14043085)

here's the link to the issue as found on wkhtmltopdf:

https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=141

Comment: The link to the issue as found on wkhtmltopdf is no longer active. Do you know if this is still an issue or whether it has been fixed in the latest version?

Comment: I don't know if it has been fixed. It appears the project left goog, maybe have a look on github: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues to find the issue there.

Answer (score 0):

wicked_pdf is too slow and many troubles.
I replaced it with this nice gem: https://github.com/Studiosity/grover .