# wicked_pdf is hanging on rails application - rails 4.2.5 - ruby 2.3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, wicked-pdf

I have tried to implement WickedPDF to generate PDF's from html pages. When I add the .pdf extension to the URL the page seems to process but the PDF is not being rendered in dev or prod environments.

I have tried this in production (Heroku) and the message returned is:

```
at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout"
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
```

**application.rb**

```
config.middleware.use WickedPdf::Middleware
```

**controller.rb**

```
def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render :pdf => "invoice", :layout => 'show.html.erb'
      end
    end
  end
```

**Terminal response**

```
Started GET "/invoices/1.pdf" for ::1 at 2016-06-13 20:28:19 +0100
Processing by InvoicesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Invoice Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "invoices".* FROM "invoices" WHERE "invoices"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered invoices/show.html.erb within layouts/application (39.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 109ms (Views: 107.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
"***************[\"/Users/justdanlee/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/wkhtmltopdf\", \"-q\", \"file:////var/folders/zq/6w81cths1jscg4dfnn56jsfm0000gn/T/wicked_pdf20160613-1291-34i0va.html\", \"/var/folders/zq/6w81cths1jscg4dfnn56jsfm0000gn/T/wicked_pdf_generated_file20160613-1291-17z0i3b.pdf\"]***************"
```

Is this a known issue?

Comment: Check this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12517640/why-does-pdfkit-wkhtmltopdf-hang-but-renders-pdf-as-expected-when-rails-app-is-k/14043085#14043085

Comment: Back to the drawing board on this one, I think.